# Which of the following methods is more efficient

Tags: arrays, data-structures, time-complexity, big-o, space-complexity

**Problem Statement:-** Given an array of integers and an integer k, print all the pairs in the array whose sum is k

**Method 1:-**
Sort the array and maintain two pointers low and high, start iterating...

Time Complexity - O(nlogn)

Space Complexity - O(1)

**Method 2:-**
Keep all the elements in the dictionary and do the process

Time Complexity - O(n)

Space Complexity - O(n)

---

Now, out of above 2 approaches, which one is the most efficient and on what basis I am going to compare the efficiency, time (or) space in this case as both are different in both the approaches

Comment: What makes you think that there is an objective ordering comparing space and time complexity? On what would it be based? If you have lots of space, but not much time, you would prefer lower time complexity. If you have almost no space, but lots of time, you would prefer lower space complexity.

Comment: Decide which is more important.  If you are space-constrained then you may be force to accept a time cost and vice-versa.  BTW: "Sort the array" is not O(1) for either Time or Space.

Comment: @AlanK There are in-place sort-algorithms with O(1) *additional* memory used. It is kind of trivial that any algorithm with input length n would use at least Theta(n) *total* memory.

Comment: @AlanK, I wrote O(1) for space because No additional space/memory has been created for solving the problem... we are using the same array which is given... so constant space complexity O(1)... Hope you agree with my approach

Comment: Thanks, everyone for clarification of my question.

Comment: It's not clear to me how method 2 is supposed to work, but which approach is better depends on how big your expected inputs are, whether you are likely to be constrained by space, and the size of any constant factors between the two algorithms.

Comment: @Lee Dictionaries take O(1) time for lookup/searching an element in it. so for n elements, it will be O(n)

Comment: How are you going to be able to only search N elements when you're looking for pairs of numbers? There are N^2 possible pairs.

Comment: This size of the answer is Ω(n^2) in the worst case, so it will take that long just to print.

Answer (score 0):

1. I've left my comment above for reference.
2. It was hasty.  You do allow O(nlogn) time for the Method 1 sort (I now think I understand?) and that's fair (apologies;-).
3. What happens next?  If the input array must be used again, then you need a sorted copy (the sort would not be in-place) which adds an O(n) space requirement.
4. The "iterating" part of Method 1 also costs ~O(n) time.
5. But loading up the dictionary in Method 2 is also ~O(n) time (presumably a throw-away data structure?) and dictionary access - although ~O(1) - is slower (than array indexing).

Bottom line: O-notation is helpful if it can identify an "overpowering cost" (rendering others negligible by comparison), but without a hint at use-cases (typical and boundary, details like data quantities and available system resources etc), questions like this (seeking a "generalised ideal" answer) can't benefit from it.

Often some simple proof-of-concept code and performance tests on representative data can make "the right choice obvious" (more easily and often more correctly than speculative theorising).

Finally, in the absence of a clear performance winner, there is always "code readability" to help decide;-)

Comment: hey, can u tell if [https://leetcode.com/problems/find-the-duplicate-number/discuss/394883/Please-help-oror-Time-and-Space-complexity] has O(n) space or not

Comment: @user2978343: It's been a while since I played with Python but at first glance - yes.  In order to return the sum of the list's excess (duplicated) items' values, it creates a set (for which the space cost is proportional to the length of the list).  Note that the code doesn't "have" O(n) space, rather "given a list of n items, it costs O(n) (additional) space" to return the result. (The summing operation has a time but (presumably) no space cost.)